# Julia iterates over `Base.Iterators.Reverse`

Tags: for-loop, iterator, julia

```
for i in Iterators.reverse(Iterators.drop([1,2], 1))
    println(i)
end
```

```
MethodError: no method matching iterate(::Base.Iterators.Reverse{Base.Iterators.Drop{Array{Int64,1}}})
Closest candidates are:
  iterate(!Matched::LibGit2.GitRevWalker) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/LibGit2/src/walker.jl:29
  iterate(!Matched::LibGit2.GitRevWalker, !Matched::Any) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/LibGit2/src/walker.jl:29
  iterate(!Matched::Base.EnvDict) at env.jl:119
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at ./In[1]:1
 [2] include_string(::Function, ::Module, ::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1091
```

Below version runs correctly

```
for i in Iterators.reverse(collect(Iterators.drop([1,2], 1)))
    println(i)
end
```

Why is `collect` required?

My julia version is 1.5.3, running on WSL2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the the error message: `collect` is required because there is `no method matching iterate(::Base.Iterators.Reverse{Base.Iterators.Drop{Array{Int64,1}}})`. From the documentation of `reverse`:

> Not all iterator types `T` support reverse-order iteration. If `T` doesn't, then iterating over `Iterators.reverse(itr::T)` will
> throw a `MethodError` because of the missing iterate methods for `Iterators.Reverse{T}`. (To implement these methods, the
> original iterator `itr::T` can be obtained from `r = Iterators.reverse(itr)` by `r.itr`.)